# Missing assembly Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Utility.dll

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

Can not find Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Utilities.dll

During analysis of a custom application the decompiler comes up and asked for the above dll.

I looked around and searched my PC and then the internet, no one knows where to get the file.

Answer (score 1):

The file is part of the Microsoft ROM image and can be downloaded from a real device. The file is named \windows\Microsoft.WindowsMobile.dll:

Microsoft.WindowsMobile.dll:
Microsoft.WindowsMobile, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Comment: So, where you not Debugging on the same version of WM that your device had? Also, I'm curious: Are you [hjgode](http://community.intermec.com/t5/General-Development-Developer/Slaying-the-virtual-memory-monster/td-p/16764)?

Comment: As said, that was an analysis. I used .Net Explorer to look at the implementation inside an exe). The app was not running on the device but load in a .Net disassembler. And, yes, I am hjgode.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem.

I found these dll in:

```
 C:\Program Files\Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK R2\Managed Libraries
```

if you don't have Windows Mobile SDK yet, you'd better download it.